# Problem with the width of a single bar in a barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, bar-chart

I do not know how to formulate my question, so here is the problem:

my code:

```
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="count")+
  scale_fill_grey(labels = c("Besetzt", "Unbesetzt"))+
  labs(y="Anzahl an Kästen",
       x="Objekt",
       caption="Fig. 1: Vergleich des Besatzes der Objekte an denen die Kästen angebracht sind")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

and here is my plot:
[image: It shows the numbers of occupied (grey) and unoccupied (black) bat boxes dependent on the object the bat box is mounted on]

My problem is the first bar Balkon. It is double the width of the others, because no bat box mounted on a Balkon is occupied. How can I change it, that the black part of the bar Balkon has the same width as the others.

I am very thankfull for ervery help I can get.

Comment: future note: when posting question provide also the data itself and the complete piece of code so that the community will be able to reproduce easily and help you. you can read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the follwing line:

`...geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="count")`

To:

`...geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'), stat="count")`

This will unify the size of the bars